# How to resolve "waiting for event "filechooser" error in playwright python for file upload where input!=file

Tags: robotframework, playwright, playwright-python

I have to upload an excel file using browse option :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phldg.png)

DOM structure looks something like this:
Input field DOM :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spEyN.png)
Browse DOM:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZAe8.png)

I am working on Robot framework using **Python **with **playwright**.

Code that I used was:
`cwd = os.getcwd() filepath = os.path.join(cwd, 'Demo\\Test\\File.xlsx') with playwright_POC.page.expect_file_chooser() as fc_info: playwright_POC.page.click(<locator for browse button>) file_chooser = fc_info.value file_chooser.set_files(filepath)`

However when I run this, I get below error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HnLj.png)

Can somebody please let me know what went wrong here, also if some reference can be shared to resolve this error?
Already tried areas:
https://playwright.dev/python/docs/input#upload-files
https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-event-file-chooser

Comment: How big is the image file?, as I can see default timeout of 30seconds been exceeded